# Login using jQuery, PHP for Cordova

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am building my first Cordova application and it requires a login system (no sign-up). I'll be using jQuery Ajax along with PHP and MySQL. But since jQuery is client side, I am afraid anyone will be able to login to the app using the developer console. For example on success the code will look something like this:

**UPDATE**

Before the success, I will take input from the input fields and send a post request to my web server. It will check the MySQL database and if the details are correct, JSON data will be sent back to the Ajax request containing the details of the user.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "https://www.mywebserver.com/login.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { username : "saifi", password: "saifi" },
  dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function( data ) {
  if(data.status == '1'){
    window.localStorage["userName"] = data.uname;
    window.localStorage["userId"] = data.uid;             
    $.mobile.changePage("home.html"); //or window.location.href = 'home.html';
  }else{
      alert('Login failed, try again!');
  }
});
```

Now in PHP we use sessions and cookies to check whether someone is logged in or not and since PHP is backend, no one could register it manually. However, in jQuery, what if someone simply goes to the inspector console and register the session manually? He'll be able to log in without even having an account.

So what would be the best way to solve this? (Using: HTML, CSS, jQuery and Javascript, PHP for Cordova)

**For those** who're wondering on how can someone open developer console on a mobile app, he just have to extract the code from the apk/ipa and then run the cordova app on a browser.

Comment: Sessions can't be set in the console .. They can be accessed .. But the session variable itself -- For example if you had one that looked like `$_SESSION[isLoggedIn'] = 1` -- Users would not be able to manually set that variable to 1 -- or `Logged In` manually --  That can only be **set** on the **server side**

Comment: Is it a problem if he can log in? It will basically mean the user will be able to see the views (which he has in the client side code anyway). But all the requests will fail as the server side (at least should) checks every requests to see if its valid

Comment: @Zak Try this, open developer console and enter this: `window.localStorage["name"] = "Jon";` press enter and Jon will be stored in the localStorage variable 'name'. Try entering this to see it yourself: `window.localStorage["name"]; //will output Jon` . As mentioned before, I know it can't be done when using PHP but this is a cordova app so everything has to be done through web services. So it's like i'll send a request to the server using Ajax then on the client side, check whether login was successful or not.

Comment: @JimL Basically, after logging in, there will be voting section so if he doesn't logs in, it will result in fake voting.

Comment: @Saifi no, because when you submit a vote (or any other data) the server side should always check if the request is valid. Meaning checking if the user is logged in and the session is valid, and that the form data is valid. So at best he will get a worthless UI that will error out every single request he attempts to run.

Comment: @JimL See, the proper flow that I want is: User opens app; enters user & pass; I send a post request to the server via ajax; if details are correct, user's details are sent back to ajax request; on client side, if login was successful, user is redirected to voting page. User's details are stored in either localStorage or sessionStorage. The main problem is, this data can be manipulated using the developer's console so how can I ensure that a user doesn't fakes his login and send a fake vote.

Comment: you need some way of authenticating that the request is from the user. You can do so by returning a session key with the user data which will then be passed with every request that requires authorization. A simple way to do this is using a JWT, here you can add the user data into the token, and sign it on the server side before passing it to the client. If the client tries to manipulate the user data in the token it will no longer match the signature and it will be invalid.

Comment: Yeah, seems logical. Will give it a try, thanks ton!